# SQL Query in Historytable Status

Tags: sql, logic, operator-keyword

i've got a simple logic question for the sql query.

There is a history table for some articles and the articles got a row with a status_id. An article can have all kind of status and i just want to get these articles, which never had a given status. for example:

```
articlename | status_id
article1    |  2
article1    |  1
article1    |  3
article2    |  2
article2    |  3
article3    |  2
article3    |  3


SELECT * FROM article WHERE article.status_id != 2 GROUP BY article.id
```

This is just the wrong code i get "article1" because it has 2 rows which fit in this statement. I think the solution is simple, but i can't get at the moment -.-

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Yuck Article1 **did** have `status_id = 2` - it's the first row in the table :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `NOT IN` to remove all the articles that have had a status of "2".

```
/* NOT IN BASED APPROACH */
SELECT * 
FROM article 
WHERE article.id NOT IN (
    SELECT article.id 
    FROM article
    WHERE article.status_id = 2)

/* NOT EXISTS BASED APPROACH */
SELECT * 
FROM article 
WHERE article.id NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM article
    WHERE article.status_id = 2)

/* JOIN BASED APPROACH */
SELECT *
FROM   article a1 LEFT JOIN
       article a2 
       ON a1.id = a2.id 
       AND a2.status_id = 2
WHERE  a2.id IS NULL
```

Comment: this is the answer, nice! but the "IN" operator would cause slow performance. any different ideas?

Comment: @alabama I've put 3 different approaches up now - you'll need to test which is fastest for your scenario, as different DBMSs will all behave differently.

Comment: thanks for your solution, it worked pretty nice. the join approach is the fastest on the MySQL database.

Comment: +1 - although, what about if the sub-query for the `NOT EXISTS()` version was correlated?